# reading from the same queue simultaneously with multiple subprocesses

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to simultaneously run three different python processes that should communicate together in this order:

- process1: this is reading stuff from websocket and every 10 minutes passing it to the queue.
- process2: reading the data from queue every 10 minutes and storing it to db.
- process3: this should read the data from the same queue every 10 minutes and making API calls.

Every process should run in parallel.

For some reason this will get a bit cumbersome as both process2 and process3 should read from the same queue the same data and seems like only second process is executing the code. It is required to have the thirs process in parallel so that it wouldn't block the first and second process as it might take some time to process the API calls. Is this a correct approach for this specific problem or should I use multithreading instead?

Here is a short illustation of the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool

def process1(queue, config):
    # implementation of process 1
    while True:
        # Track websocket and get data
        data = track_websocket()

        # Put the data in the queue
        queue.put(data)

        time.sleep(600)  # Wait for 10 minutes

def process2(queue):
    # implementation of process 2
    data = queue.get()
    parse_and_save_data(data)

def process3(queue):
    #implementation of process 3
    data = queue.get()
    api_results = make_api_calls(data)
    save_results_to_database(api_results)


queue = Queue()

first_process = Process(target=process1, args=(queue, config,))
first_process.start()
second_process = Process(target=process2, args=(queue, config,))
second_process.start()
third_process = Process(target=process3, args=(queue, config,))
third_process.start()
```

Tried to run three processes in parallel that would communicate together.